# Hide Last Item in Drupal 8 Multi Value Field Form Widgets

Tags: drupal, field, drupal-8, multivalue

Does anyone know if there is a way to hide the last item  in the form for a multi-valued field, so that only the "add-more" button shows, and no empty deltas are shown. I already tried hiding the item if it is empty in hook_form_alter,  but then the add-more button adds two items. It seems that the delta value is upped by one somewhere in the ajax process, and I have not been able to prevent the first ajax call from then adding TWO items instead of one, even if I unset

```
$form['myfield']['widget'][0]
```

Has anyone had success with this? Otherwise I will have to use Paragraphs instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks jmux. Here is how to remove empty next widget only on entity edit forms and keep it on entity add forms:

```
function HOOK_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $fieldname = 'field_fieldname';
  if (isset($form[$fieldname])) {
    $max_delta = $form[$fieldname]['widget']['#max_delta'];
    if ($form_state->getBuildInfo()['callback_object']->getEntity()->isNew() == FALSE && isset($form[$fieldname]['widget'][1])) {
      unset($form[$fieldname]['widget'][$max_delta]);
      $form[$fieldname]['widget']['#max_delta'] = $max_delta-1; 
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't have the field on multiple entities use HOOK_form_FORM_ID_alter()

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'myFormID'){
        $field_name='my_field_name';
        if (!empty($form[$field_name])) {
            $max_delta = $form[$field_name]['widget']['#max_delta'];
            unset($form[$field_name]['widget'][$max_delta]);
            $form[$field_name]['widget']['#max_delta'] = $max_delta-1; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this?  Obviously the first line is wrong as it is missing the $formstate variable, so just wanted to see if you had tested it.  Also, did you consider using hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for a little more specificity and efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

This solution preprocesses the field_multiple_value_form theme hook so it will apply to all multivalue fields.

When the field has at least one value, remove the last item from the table, which is the empty widget.

```
function HOOK_preprocess_field_multiple_value_form(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['table'])) {
    $row_count = count($variables['table']['#rows']);
    if ($row_count > 1) {
      unset($variables['table']['#rows'][$row_count - 1]);
    }
  }
}
```